# EJB 3.1 Lookup from Standalone Java program

Tags: java, ejb

I have a Stateless Session Bean defined using EJB 3.1 Specs and deployed on WAS 8.5 server.

Have a Standalone, Java application program which needs to do EJB lookup and call the Business method

How do I write code to do the EJB lookup from the Standalone Java Program.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a Remote Context.  There are lots of documentation which cover this

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b15505/access.htm
http://openejb.codehaus.org/hello-world.html
EJB3/UseInitialContextToLookupEJB.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0415_EJB3/UseInitialContextToLookupEJB.htm
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project